# Insert Textbox values in Array in Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a textbox in which user can add some values one by one. Now, when user click on add button I want to insert value that user enter into array one by one. I am doing this but I am getting the wrong result. The length of array is not increasing. Say If I entered 2 values then the length of array remain 1. I don't know what's the error. Below is my code:-

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input_add_prod_grp" name="input_add_prod_grp" placeholder="Enter Group Name" />

<button class="btn default btn-xs btn_add_input_prod_grp" name="btn_add_input_prod_grp" id="add_group">Add</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".btn_add_input_prod_grp").click(function(){

var add_input_grp = $("input[name$='input_add_prod_grp']").val();

var newArray = [];
newArray.push('Ungrouped');
$( "input[name='input_add_prod_grp']" ).each(function() {
    newArray.push($( this ).val());

});
console.log(newArray.length);
});
```

Now, If I enter more than 1 value then length of array remain 1. I don't know why.. Please help me out.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take you array outside:

```
var newArray = [];
$(".btn_add_input_prod_grp").click(function(){

   var add_input_grp = $("input[name$='input_add_prod_grp']").val();


  newArray.push(add_input_grp);
  console.log(newArray.length);
});
```

JSFIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/c19u6fa2/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newArray = [];
$(".btn_add_input_prod_grp").click(function() {

  var add_input_grp = $("input[name$='input_add_prod_grp']").val();

  newArray.push('Ungrouped');
  $("input[name='input_add_prod_grp']").each(function() {
    newArray.push($(this).val());

  });
  console.log(newArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input_add_prod_grp" name="input_add_prod_grp" placeholder="Enter Group Name" />

<button class="btn default btn-xs btn_add_input_prod_grp" name="btn_add_input_prod_grp" id="add_group">Add</button>
```

Put the initialization outside of click event. Inside click event it is always reinitialize over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You are making newArray empty when you click on button so the old values are deleting from that array to avoid this you have to move that to outside of your function along with default values you have only one input box you no need to write each you can get directly that value from your variable

```
            var newArray = ['Ungrouped'];

            $(".btn_add_input_prod_grp").click(function(){

                var add_input_grp = $("input[name$='input_add_prod_grp']").val();

                newArray.push(add_input_grp);

                console.log(newArray.length);

            });
```